# Emacs started as emerge by `git mergetool'

Tags: emacs

I want to run different init script when Emacs is started into Emerge mode directly by `git mergetool'.

Seems emacs is called with the command line:
"""
  -l file, --load file
  Load the lisp code in the file file.
"""

However, how should I know inside dot-emacs script it's invoked differently?  Which variable should I probe.